# Haskel - Iterating through a list of lists of lists

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to print the integers from a list of lists of lists and am struggling to know the most effective way of doing this.

An example of this list is as follows:

```
[ [ [ 2,3 ], [ 1,6 ] ]
, [ [ 5,9 ], [ 2,9 ] ]
, [ [ 6,2 ], [ 7,7 ] ] ]
```

My hope is to print a string such as "231659296277".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a 3 layered list, you can just concatenate it twice:

```hs
concat . concat $
    [ [ [ 2,3 ], [ 1,6 ] ]
    , [ [ 5,9 ], [ 2,9 ] ]
    , [ [ 6,2 ], [ 7,7 ] ]
    ]
-- [2,3,1,6,5,9,2,9,6,2,7,7]
```

If you want to convert it to a string, then you can `>>= show`:

```hs
[2,3,1,6,5,9,2,9,6,2,7,7] >>= show
-- "231659296277"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes alot of sense.